# Java print JPEG from disk

Tags: java, printing

I have put 2 buttons on my java page to print and email it. I have solved the email requirement

```
    if (e.getSource().equals(btnEmail)){
        dialog.setVisible(true); // to visible the dialog
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            String format = "jpg";
            final String fileName = "C:\\xxxxxxxx--" + format;
            Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
            File file = new File(fileName);  
            ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, file);

            while (true){
                boolean exists = file.exists();  
                if (!exists){        // It returns false if File or directory does not exist 
                    return;
                } else {
                    String to = "xxxx@hotmail.com";
                    String username = "xxxx@gmail.com";
                    final String password = "xxxx";

                    //Get the session object  
                    Properties props = new Properties();
                    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);//change accordingly  
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
                        message.setSubject("Printout from Java Exe");
                        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                        messageBodyPart.setText("Printout");
                        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                        // Part two is attachment
                        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
                        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                        messageBodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());
                        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                        // Send the complete message parts
                        message.setContent(multipart);
                         // Send message
                        Transport.send(message);

                        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

                    } catch (MessagingException e ?????1) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e1);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (AWTException | IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        dialog.setVisible(false); // set visibility to false
 } else if (e.getSource().equals(btnPrint)){

// This is where I'm stuck - Should be easy - just output a JPEG from disk to Printer ?????
 }
```

This is where I'm stuck - Should be easy - just output a JPEG from disk to Printer ?????

Comment: Sorry about the formatting !!

Comment: Instead of apologizing for the formatting, why don't you fix it?

Comment: Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Thanks for any help on this. I use this site maybe once a year or so and then only after a couple of days after digging!    How do I put a newline here?  How do I edit or delete a posted questions?

Comment: I opened a code block above and closed it but the code came out wrong! How do I edit this?

Comment: if you hit the edit button under your post you should be able to add anything (save at the end) - just put the new program there highlight it and hit the curly braces

Answer (score 0):

I have used this program and it calls up the dialog - I dont have a printer so try to see if it actually prints - substitute screenFullImage for bim:

```
class HelloWorldPrinter implements Printable, ActionListener {


public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                    PrinterException {

    if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
     * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
     */
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    /* Now we perform our rendering */
//        g.drawString("Hello world!", 100, 100);
BufferedImage bim=null;
try {
  bim=ImageIO.read(new File("../black.jpg"));
}
catch (Exception ex) { System.err.println("error in bim "+ex); }

g.drawImage(bim, 0, 0, null);

    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
     job.setPrintable(this);
     boolean ok = job.printDialog();
     if (ok) {
         try {
              job.print();
         } catch (PrinterException ex) {
          /* The job did not successfully complete */
         }
     }
}

public static void m() {

    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello World Printer");
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
       public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
    });
    JButton printButton = new JButton("Print Hello World");
    printButton.addActionListener(new HelloWorldPrinter());
    f.add("Center", printButton);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

--

change

```
public static void m() {
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

and

```
BufferedImage bim=null;
try {
  bim=ImageIO.read(new File("...")); // fill in whatever name the file is saved in the whole path e.g. c:/mypath/filename
}
catch (Exception ex) { System.err.println("error in bim "+ex); }

g.drawImage(bim, 0, 0, null);
```

To print a smaller size image try this

```
BufferedImage b0=new BufferedImage(bim.getWidth()/2, bim.getHeight()/2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics g0=b0.getGraphics();
g0.drawImage(bim, b0.getWidth(), b0.getHeight(), null);
```

now print this image instead of bim:

```
g.drawImage(b0, 0, 0, null);
```

Comment: Thanks @gpasch.  I started in a new project and set up new class HelloWorldPrinter and substituted bim as you suggested but I am new to Java. Of course there were errors which I thought had to do with missing imports at the top but this didn't solve all of the errors. I know I should take a couple of weeks to learn Java properly but I usually learn better from studying working examples. I think I need another little pointer

Comment: I dont know what errors you are getting what have you changed etc - post the changed program then I might see it

Comment: I'm using Eclipse which I think is similar to Netbeans
I started a new project called "HelloWorldPrinter"
Then created a class with the same name.

I imported a load of libraries and I was going to delete those not needed later.

When I compared the 2 files I realized there were still missing libraries which I have now fixed.

My code is now error free.

Comment: As I said - a newbie - so can you help me to run this as there is no "main".

Should I change... 

public static void m() {

to main string args etc.

If I can get this working I should be able to modify my code.

Comment: yes m() is my modified main()  I will edit the above

Comment: Thank you very much @gpasch for your patience with me.  It seems to be OK now except it just prints top left quarter of file.   I may be able to fix things but my old brain is tiring and you may know what needs doing.  Cheers

Comment: Actually I've just reducedmagnification and I can get left half only

Comment: OK I've done some more digging and I need to reduce the size of the image first.      Any ideas?

Comment: I may still have your attention.......This came about when a friend asked me to add _print_ and _email_ facilities to his java program....I don't know java well but managed to get most of it done - originally I used the following to _print_  '   try {
if (! table.print()) {
           System.err.println("User cancelled printing");
       }
   } catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException ee) {
       System.err.format("Cannot print %s%n", ee.getMessage());
   }   
' (formatting issues) but this just printed the frame. I need whole page. maybe just a simple change to ! table.print()???

Comment: I dont know what table is - for the image to reduce size see the above technique -

Comment: I really thought you would have tired of me by now and when you replied I thought that would solve my problem. However because of my inexperience in Java I'm not sure if your last post (To print a smaller size etc) was to be added to existing code or replace some of it.   I have tried 3 different replacements with no luck. We've come this far - maybe I can push my luck a little further.  If I've still got you, how can I offer some feedback or something for your perseverance.